# Is it possible to use USB token as file storage

Tags: usb, security, token

Is it possible to store and retrieve files other than certificate in USB etoken? I would like to use it as read-only USB flash disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, Etoken acts s a normal USB device.
http://www.safenet-inc.com/multi-factor-authentication/authenticators/pki-usb-authentication/etoken-pro/

You can modify any usb device permissions and file system.

Comment: How can we format them and use them as normal drived? Windows 10 diskpart does not seem to recognize it at all...